# Active Record "where" query from parent resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to create a Query that evaluates if the parent object has receives at least two likes. If he has, then include it in the random query.

I tried something like this but it didn't work.

```
@attachments = Attachment.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.id = attachments.user_id').where("received_likes_count > ?",2).order("random()")
```

Comment: `users.id = attachments.id` it is very strange!

Comment: should it be attachments.user_id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you? I'm envisioning your User is the parent, and the attachments table has a user_id, but I'm not entirely sure based on your wording of the question.

The main trick of this is it uses a sub-select to gather ids for use in the IN clause.

```
@attachments = Attachment.where(
  'user_id IN (
     SELECT id FROM users WHERE received_likes_count > ?
  )', 2
).order('random()')
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL?

```
@attachments = Attachment.joins(:users).where("received_likes_count > ?",2).order("rand()")
```